# How does express know the difference between a static and a dynamic request?

Tags: node.js, express

This is the code that I see everywhere for a simple static web server using node.js and express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(8080);
```

My question is how does express know when the request is for a static page vs. a dynamic page? For example, why would /index.html be served from the public folder and not from dynamic templates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of the routes you define as a chain of checks on the path defined in the URL. Express iterates one by one through each check looking for a match; once it finds one, it executes that callback.

In this case, express.static is defining a bunch of path checks for each file in the `public` directory. If you `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` *before* your `app.get('/index.html', function(req, res) { ...` code, and there is an index.html file in there, it will use the static file over the dynamic one.

That's basically it.

Comment: This actually comes from Connect, btw: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html